# How to customize the title of a table view?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, alignment, customization, title

In my app, i need to show two datas in each titles of a table view like this

[image]

In left side the day & in right side the date will be shown.

The problem here is, the day & dates are not properly aligned because of variations in letters. The day should be left aligned whereas the date should be right aligned.

What should i do to get this? Please give a brief explanation

Thanks in Advance

Comment: by titles, do you mean section headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

method to create your own section view. I believe you need to do something like this:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *myView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
    UIImageView *bgImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"name_of_bg_image.png"]];
    [myView addSubview:bgImage];
    [bgImage release];

    UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(SomeFrameHere)];
...set label properties and text...
    [myView addSubview:lbl1];
    [lbl1 release];

... create 2nd label with alignment to the right border here...

    return myView;
}
```